# How i upload images using ionic 4 in PWA

Tags: json, image, upload, ionic4, progressive-web-apps

Hi i have a ionic develop with and works great in the front end, but i dont know how send this picture to backend.? JSON Objetc? String? base64? how i convert the input file to base64? considering this pwa and cordova doesnt work.

at my html have this

```
<div class="btn">
          <label>
            <ion-icon slot="start" name="camera"></ion-icon>
            Sucursal de Instalación
            <input type="file" style="display: none;" (change)="subirInstalacion($event)">
          </label>
        </div>
```

at my ts, i have this

```
subirInstalacion(fileInput: any) {
    //trae imagen de la galeria 
      this.fileData = <File>fileInput.target.files[0];
      this.preview();
  }

  preview() {
    // vista previa de la imagen
    var mimeType = this.fileData.type;
    if (mimeType.match(/image\/*/) == null) {
      return;
    }

    let reader = new FileReader();      
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.fileData); 
    reader.onload = (_event) => { 
      this.previewSucursalInstalacion = reader.result; 
    }
  }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Where did you find an example of how to upload pics on a PWA?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what kind of back end you want to use.

You either need to set up your own server and web api, something like [this](https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-image-upload-storage/) or [this](https://devdactic.com/ionic-image-upload-nodejs-server/). However, it will need more code for a real world use for security and such.

Alternatively you can put it into the cloud. There are lots of services to host images.

Firebase is a popular one. There is also an interesting one called [Uploadсare](https://uploadcare.com). There is a tutorial series [that combines these two technologies](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYxzS__5yYQnpK36-GJjm7IEAuHR7IExa).